# Eclipse RCP - cant resolve importing libraries in final build

Tags: eclipse, jar, build, export, rcp

I try to build/export Eclipse RCP product. I have several JAR libraries (not external JARs but they are inside project root folder). I am able to launch application/product in Eclipse environment but i cannot export it as Plug-in Development/Eclipse product. There is no error during exporting but when i try to run my application .exe file the error occurs:

```
"An error has occurred. See the log file:
C://...configuration/123123.log"
```

Inside log there is:

```
    !SESSION 2015-12-18 08:50:22.759 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.8.0_60
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=pl_PL
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2015-12-18 08:50:23.284
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The import com.amazonservices cannot be resolved
    MarketplaceWebServiceOrdersConfig cannot be resolved to a type
    MarketplaceWebServiceOrdersConfig cannot be resolved to a type

    at smoothflow.Application.<init>(Application.java:9)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:184)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2015-12-18 08:50:23.309
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
java.lang.IllegalStateException: BundleContext is no longer valid
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.checkValid(BundleContextImpl.java:983)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.removeBundleListener(BundleContextImpl.java:334)
    at org.eclipse.ui.plugin.AbstractUIPlugin$2.bundleChanged(AbstractUIPlugin.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:902)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
```

EDIT: ok i see that when i export project to .exe, logs.zip file is created. Inside this log there are tons of errors.

Those errors looks like missing JAR: The import XXX cannot be resolved XXX - package that is inside JAR library
    1. ERROR in

```
C:\Users\X\workspaceRPC\SmoothFlow\src\app\amazonCalls\BaseAmazonCall.java (at line 3)
        import com.amazonservices.mws.orders._2013_09_01.MarketplaceWebServiceOrdersAsyncClient;
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    The import com.amazonservices cannot be resolved
```

EDIT: Greg thank you for Your help, i have added in build.properties all the JARs but the problem still exists (the same errors). My build.properties looks like:

```
source.. = src/
output.. = bin/
bin.includes = plugin.xml,\
               META-INF/,\
               .,\
               lib/,\
               lib/FastInfoset.jar,\
               lib/MWSClientJavaRuntime-1.0.jar,\
               lib/MWSOrders_2013-09-01_v2015-09-24.jar,\
               ...
jars.compile.order = .,\
```

Comment: Have you included all the necessary jars in the 'build.properties' for the plugins?

Comment: I have them inside build.properties under bookmark "Runtime" (Classpath window) and also under MANIFEST.MF defined as Bundle-ClassPath.
Should i add those JARs somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

As well as listing the Jars in the MANIFEST.MF (shown on the Runtime tab in the editor) you must also list the jars in the 'build.properties' file. This is shown on the 'Build' tab of the MANIFEST.MF/plugin.xml/build.properties editor.

An example:

[image: Build properties]

In this example I have three jars in a 'lib' directory included in the build.

The build.properties file itself will look like:

```
source.. = src/
output.. = bin/
bin.includes = META-INF/,\
               .,\
               plugin.properties,\
               plugin.xml,\
               about.html,\
               about_files/,\
               lib/,\
               lib/jogg-0.0.7.jar,\
               lib/jorbis-0.0.15.jar,\
               lib/vorbisspi1.0.2.jar,\
               icons/
```

Everything you want included in the plugin must be listed in the build.properties.